# Using one private link to connect to various Azure PaaS Services

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

Do I need to set up multiple private links with different private endpoints to connect from my Azure VM to say an Azure Storage account  or Azure SQL DB or only one private link will do and I can use that private link with multiple Azure PaaS Services that are serviced by Private Link?

Comment: Any update on this question? Does the reply solve your question?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create different private endpoint connections for different Azure PaaS Services. Also, private endpoints must be deployed in the same region as the virtual network.

Here are some key details about private endpoints:

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview

Comment: Further,I think even for multiple instances of the SAME service eg. accessing 2 different storage accounts from single vnet(concept-any subnet in vnet can make use of private endpoint UNLIKE service endpoints),separate Private Endpoints would be needed. 
This is NOT the case with service endpoints, where same service endpoint in subnet is used for multiple INSTANCES of SAME service.